# Drawing Bounding Boxes with Gradio

Tags: gradio

I have an YOLO Classified image with bounding boxes but how do i draw the same bounding boxes on my output image in Gradio Webapp and is there anyway for me to make the user adjust the bounding boxes in gradio?

The `gr.outputs.BoundingBox` and `gr.outputs.ImageBoundingBox` does not work in gradio newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, drawing Bounding Boxes directly in gradio is not possible. You have to render them yourself onto the image in your python code. The drawback of this is that the user can not adjust the boxes on the UI.

Note, there is a [recent PR](https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/pull/3220) that has been declined. There also is a [possible workaround](https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/1836) by obtaining the bounding boxes through the cropped image.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you know of any other libraries that I can use to draw bounding boxes on an Image that the user can adjust in the UI?

Comment: No sorry, but I am not really into this field. So a little google research should help here. If you found my answer for gradio helpful, I would appreciate it if you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib to draw bounding box.
Here are sample codes

````py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 20))
ax.imshow(img_rgb)

for i, desc in enumerate(descriptors):
    
    found = False
    for name, saved_desc in descs.items():
        dist = np.linalg.norm([desc] - saved_desc, axis=1)

        if dist < 0.6:
            found = True

            text = ax.text(rects[i][0][0], rects[i][0][1], name,
                    color='b', fontsize=40, fontweight='bold')
            text.set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=10, foreground='white'), path_effects.Normal()])
            rect = patches.Rectangle(rects[i][0],
                                 rects[i][1][1] - rects[i][0][1],
                                 rects[i][1][0] - rects[i][0][0],
                                 linewidth=2, edgecolor='w', facecolor='none')
            ax.add_patch(rect)

            break
    
    if not found:
        ax.text(rects[i][0][0], rects[i][0][1], 'unknown',
                color='r', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
        rect = patches.Rectangle(rects[i][0],
                             rects[i][1][1] - rects[i][0][1],
                             rects[i][1][0] - rects[i][0][0],
                             linewidth=2, edgecolor='r', facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('result/output.png')
plt.show()```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).